# Regular expression to extract text from XML-ish data using GNU sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file full of lines extracted from an XML file using "gsed regexp -i FILENAME". The lines in the file are all of one of either format:

```
<field number='1' name='Account' type='STRING'W/>

<field number='2' name='AdvId' type='STRING'W>
```

I've inserted a 'W' in the end which represents optional whitespace. The order and number of properties are not necessarily the same in all lines throughout the file although "number" is always before "type".

What I'm searching for is a regular expression "regexp" that I can give to gnu sed so that this command:

gsed regexp -i FILENAME

gives me a file with lines looking like this:

1 STRING

2 STRING

I don't care about the amount of whitespace in the result as long as there is some after the number and a newline at the end of each line.

I'm sure it is possible, but I just can't figure out how in a reasonable amount of time. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot,
  jules

Comment: I was actually overlooking it. I've upvoted your answer because it gave me what I was asking for and the xsh solution from choroba because, while it didn't really answer the question, it did point out an elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this can be optimized, but it works for me and answers your question:

```
 sed "s/^.*number='\([0-9]*\)'.*type='\(.*\)'.*$/\1 \2/" <filename>
```

Saying that, I think the others are right, if you have an XML-file you should use an XML-parser.

Answer (score 2):

Using [xsh](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a Perl wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open file.xml ;
for //field echo @number @type ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're *much* better off using a command line XML tool such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/). That will integrate well with the shell and let you perform XPath searches. It's XML-aware so it'll handle character encodings, whitespace correctly etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simple cut should work for you:

cut -f2,6 -d"'" --output-delimiter=" "

If you really want sed:

sed -r "s/.*'(.*)'.*type='(.*)'.*/\1 \2/"

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
sed -r "s/<field [^>]*?number='([0-9]+)'[^>]*?type='([^']+)'[^>]*>/\1 \2/"
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using an XML parser, but if you had to use sed:

`sed 's/<field number=\'(.*?)\'.*?type=\'(.*?)\'/\1 \2`

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -ni "/<field .*>/s@^.*[[:space:]]number='\\([^']\\+\\).*[[:space:]]type='\\([^']\\+\\).*@\1 \2@p" FILENAME
```

Or if you don't mind contents of number and type to be optional:

```
sed -ni "/<field .*>/s@^.*[[:space:]]number='\\([^']*\\).*[[:space:]]type='\\([^']*\\).*@\1 \2@p" FILENAME
```

Just change from `[^']\\+` to `[^']*` at your preference.